# Django Intro Tutorial - Invoke Python Shell

Tags: django

I am new to django and am starting to go through the documenation and the poll tutorial. Install etc has been no problem and I have gotten as far as creating and activating the simple model however I am now trying to invoke the Python shell using

```
python manage.py shell
```

but I keep getting the below error each time.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Programming\Djang\mysite>python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py",
 line 81, in handle_noargs
    self.run_shell(shell=interface)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py",
 line 61, in run_shell
    return getattr(self, shell)()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py",
 line 44, in ipython
    ip()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py",
 line 37, in _ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>

    from .config.loader import Config
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\__init__.py", line 16, in <
module>
    from .application import *
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 29, i
n <module>
    from IPython.external.decorator import decorator
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\decorator\__init__.py", l
ine 4, in <module>
    from ._decorator import *
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\decorator\_decorator.py",
 line 165
    print('Error in generated code:', file=sys.stderr)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this as although I have some experience in Python I'm finding it very hard to follow the Traceback above.

Comment: It looks like you have python3 code in your python2 library. you cannot do that.  Where did you get that `IPython` install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Python 3 library (and not backward compatible) with the Python 2.7 version. You need either to reinstall `ipython` for Python 2 (in `C:\python27`) or upgrade to Python 3 (and install `ipython` in `C:\python3`)

Django is officially compatible with Python 3 since the 1.6 version.

Comment: That worked for me thank you very much. From my perspective is there anything in the Traceback above that would have made it obvious that there was an issue with compatibility (so I can know for again)?

Comment: @user3675339 The hint there was the fact there is `C:\python27` in your path and the error occurred on the `print` line, because it became a function in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work